# How to meta-analyze three effect sizes of correlations?

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression

I am searching statistical approaches to analyze three effect sizes of correlations. I would like to see the relationships among one independent variable (performance on a certain type of cognitive task) and two predictor variables (two different types of participant-related variables, e.g., working memory, IQ). Studies that I am including in my meta-analysis report Pearson correlation coefficients.

I would like to test the size of each predictor variable's influence, or direct and indirect effects on the dependent variable.

I have been reading into by myself, but could not find any information by myself so far. I would really appreciate it if I could hear suggestions on this.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say independent variable do you mean dependent?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That was a critical mistake. I will fix it right now.

Comment: I think mvmeta in R or Stata could do the trick

Comment: I read several articles and one book chapter talking about mvmeta; however it does not seem to be the package I am looking for. If I am understanding correctly, mvmeta allows us to calculate three standardized (and separately calculated) effect sizes simultaneously, whearas what I would like to do is to analyze correlations between three different variables reported by studies. So effect size would be three correlations but all of them are dependent with each other. I would appreciate it if someone can correct me if I’m misunderstanding. Thanks.

Comment: You may fit it using the meta-analytic structural equation modeling (MASEM). See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metaSEM/vignettes/Examples.html#two-stage-structural-equation-modeling-tssem for some examples.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions, @MikeCheung! Wow, this seems really cool! So, we can run SEM with meta-analytic data! I will definitely learn more about this. Thank you very much. :)